# Troubleshooting 'RasterIO error' When Cropping and Downloading .jp2 Files in QGIS with OpenJPEG and GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, jpeg-2000

I am trying to process large .jp2 files for image downloading from specified lat/lon coordinates using qgis's python packages. For context, I am working in a conda environment on a linux machine with the following versions of relevant packages openjpeg==2.4.0 and gdal==3.2.2. QGIS is able to create the rasterization layer for the relevant jp2 file and

```
gdalinfo /deep/group/aiccbootcamp/transportation/data/dvrpc/raw/2020/DelawareCo/DelawareCo_PA_Nearmap_Sp20.jp2
```

returns valid pixel statistics. However, when I try to take a crop of the .jp2 and download the imagery from the QGIS layer I get the following error:

```
Logged warning: RasterIO error: /deep/group/aicc-bootcamp/transportation/data/dvrpc/raw/2020/DelawareCo/DelawareCo_PA_Nearmap_Sp20.jp2, band 4: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: opj_set_decoded_resolution_factor() failed
```

I am wondering if anyone has found a solution to get around this issue.

Comment: The error `opj_set_decoded_resolution_factor() failed` seems to come from the OpenJPEG library, and obviously it finds something surprising in the JPEG2000 code stream. That is likely something that a user cannot bypass, and without test data even OpenJPEG developers can't say what goes wrong. As a workaround I would try to find GDAL or QGIS which has some other JPEG2000 driver. JP2ECW is probably easiest to find but otherwise Kakadu, MrSID or Luratech are also worth having a try.

Comment: Does your JP2 *really* have a 4th band? The error message could be caused by trying to read the 4th band on a RGB image which is not RGBA.